# node.js and passport-facebook do not save sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I use **[passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook)**. 
*Authorization* is no problem, i can do something and i'm authorized. 
But if i close page and open page i'm unauthorized.

```
      var month = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
      app.use(express.cookieParser());
      app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mp-api-d', cookie: {maxAge: month} }));
      app.use(passport.initialize());
      app.use(passport.session());
```

What can i do? 
I don't use any DB for session.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the session *somewhere* if you want it to persist. Typically this is in a database of some kind, although the file system is an option too. The express session middleware documentation has more on this, including a list of compatible session stores:

https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 127.0.0.1 and localhost different thing. Cookies are stored on localhost and i use 127.0.0.1